# get_page meta query not working, maybe a bug?

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

So i have the following arguments to query a custom post type:

```
$compargs = array( 
    'post_type' => 'projects',
    'meta_compare' => '=',
    'meta_key' => 'status',
    'meta_value' => 'completed',
);

$comptasks = get_pages( $compargs );
```

As expected the above returns all posts from the projects post type that have a meta_key "status" with the value of "completed".

Why is it when i try the following, it doesnt take into consideration the meta_query:

```
$compargs = array( 
    'post_type' => 'projects',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'status',
            'value'   => 'completed',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
);

$comptasks = get_pages( $compargs );
```

Is this default behavior? Should it work? Or is it just me presuming that it should?

Answer (score 1):

[`get_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/) doesn't support the full featured meta query that you can do with `WP_Query()` constructor. `get_pages()` only support meta key - value query and that is why 1st query is working and 2nd is not.

So, you have to use [`WP_Query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) in this case.